# Schedule the execution of function using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, scheduled-tasks

I need to execute a function every tot hours, right now I'm doing it manually by going to:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/controller/function
```

is there a way to schedule the execution of this function every four hours for example?

Comment: Yep, use a cron job on *nix, or the scheduler on Windows. What platform are you on? Personally I'd move this out of the web tree and run it on the CLI, unless it really _must_ be run in a web environment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using Debian Linux.

Comment: Right, use cron then - if you do a web search for 'cron php' there are _loads_ of resources for that. Works on shared accounts too, usually. And as I say, this shouldn't be in the web tree - run it on the CLI, so it will look something like `/usr/local/php /my/path/outside/the/web/tree.php <param>`.

Comment: you're right, right now the function can be executed by everyone...

Comment: @halfer just another question: inside the .php file that contains the code will I be able to get a CodeIgniter instance doing this "$CI = &get_instance ();" ?

Comment: I've never used CI before, but if you include some initialisation library, I should think it will be fine. Something needs to prepare the autoloader so it loads the classes in as you need them.

Comment: Some basic web-searching ("code igniter cli") got me [this](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Category:Advanced::CronScript/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the best case you should set cron jobs to request that URL every hour using wget or CURL in the *NIX command line:

```
0 1 * * * wget http://www.mywebsite.com/controller/function
```

As this URL is accessible publicly secure it with a parameter like http://www.mywebsite.com/controller/function?key=my_secret_key_here

Also take a look at this online service: http://cronless.com/